# solr slow response from server (when connecting via the external IP address)

Tags: solr, openstack, cloudera

We have configured a mini-cluster with 5 nodes on OpenStack. Solr has been configued on the cluster as a service via Cloudera Manager. We are using CDH 5.4.5.

When we are accessing the solr admin page via the internal IP address as a (192.168.1.X) from another server on the same network, we got the page very fast.  If we are trying to access the same solr admin page via the external IP address register by the OpenStack on the same node as the previous call (or any other servers outside the private network) then it is terribly slow to load the page.  Each .js file to load take ~ 10 seconds for the browser to received it vs ~5ms with the internal Ip.

We have assumed we add some DNS / network issues. But we tried with another web application on the same node as solr and we have not experienced this.

Then we have snoop the network on the solr server for retrieving a simple image (http://theExternalIp:8983/solr/img/hand.png) and we were able to see that it received the request from the client, then the server responded 10 seconds with the images.

Anyone has experience this ?  What would be the best to debug solr ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did your browser cached the another web application, try see its resource via browser debuger, does http code `304` returned for the resource ? Just guess ...

Comment: The browser is caching the file.  From the snoop, we are seing the browser asking if the file has been modified since X.  10 seconds later, solr is returning the HTTP 304 not modified.

Comment: Solr simply use embedded jetty provide rest API & solr admin, feels it's network limit issue in your environment.